# MSMQ: Message Queue service is not available. Error message

Tags: networking, msmq

have had MSMQ working for the past few months but I am suddenly getting this error message:

```
Message Queue service is not available.
```

This is when i test it locally when I test it in live i get the follwoing message:

```
 Unable to validate data.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to validate data.]
   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData) +4961431
   System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Decode(String encodedData, MachineKeyProtection protectionOption) +194
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken) +120

[HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.]
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken) +754
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase context, String salt) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825488
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Has anyone come across this problem where it has been working and then stops and any fixes for this?

Edit:  I had a few issues setting up msmq see:
[MSMQ creating errors: A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation / User's internal Message Queuing certificate does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496112/msmq-creating-errors-a-workgroup-installation-computer-does-not-support-the-ope)

My set up we have 6 servers which are load balanced and all have msmq set up,  the domain is set up as a Network service and there are two other server which are involved - the doamin controller which receives the messages and serach server which receives the message - i don t kow if there is a problem on all or just one particular server.  I have tried to narrow it down by using the Host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\Host )and pointing at each server at a time but they still seem to be sporadic in whther they work or not.  We do use caching so I'm not sure if this may be affecting anything...

Thanks

Comment: Did you check if the MSMQ an DTC services are running on all participating machines? Are you working with queues on remote machines - not all functionality is available when working remote. How about the access (read/ write) priviledges of the queues and users?

Comment: I'm not 100% that the 2 errors are correlated - the second error is to do with ASP.NET MVC's AntiForgeryToken, not MSMQ?

Comment: Axtually i just went into services.msc and checked that the services were running properley Message Queuing was but Message Queueing triggers had stopped so I started it and all work again Phew!! panic over!! thanks for your answers

Comment: Ahh no it hasn't - it worked once then failed with A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation.  ...

Comment: Right I think the solution may not actually be to do with the set up of msmq - as i went through the checks in my previous post  MSMQ creating errors: A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation / User's internal Message Queuing certificate does not exist  It looks like what actually happened was one of my servers ran out of memory and therefore affected the msmq service.  Also on two of the servers MSMQ was not set up properley - they only had private queues - so I had to uninstall and then reinstall checking the correct boxes (see other post)

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sounds like a dummy solution, but it will worked with me for sure.

You need to remove MSMQ and install again, but in order for the other services to actually see it you need to restart in between every step ... so What you need to do as follow:

- Remove MSMQ
- Restart Server
- Install MSMQ
- Restart Server: Noting sometime this step is not needed it depends on whether the other services are able to see the MSMQ at this level or not.

Good luck

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this problem, follow these steps: 
Log on to your computer as an administrator.
Click Start, and then click
Run.

The Run dialog box appears.
In the Open box, type
Services.msc, and then click OK.

The Services window appears.
Locate Message Queuing. Right-click
Message Queuing, and then click
Properties.

The Message Queuing Properties (Local Computer) dialog box appears.
On the Log On tab, click Local System account.
Click Apply, and then click
OK.
Stop the Message Queuing service, and then start the Message Queuing service.

Comment: Why is using the System Account better? my MSMQ service is causing some trouble sometimes and I am trying to figure out the reasons. But the service runs with the Network Service account. It that a bad thing?

Comment: You just copied this from a random Microsoft article, didn't you?