# MSMQ - Cannot see public queues

Tags: msmq

I'm new to MSMQ. I started in a Win 2008 domain controller VM, installed all features under Message Queuing category.

In Computer Management, Services and Applicatoins, Message Queing, I do see Outgoing, Private and System queues, but cannot see Public queues.

Why is that? Again, is a domain controller VM, so AD is installed, up & running.

If I go through Visual Studio's Server Explorer, I do see Public queues, but when I click refresh, I get "A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation." But I clearly see that the machine is joined to a domain - it's actually the DC!

Ideas appreciated, thanks in advance!

UPDATE: it was because of permissions were not propertly assigned during MSMQ feature setup,

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MSMQ think I'm on a workgroup computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951677/why-does-msmq-think-im-on-a-workgroup-computer)

Answer (score 3):

This may be because MSMQ is using the workgroup instead of AD.

To fix this, open RegEdit and go to the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters
```

and change the `Workgroup` field from 1 to 0