# MSMQ error c00e0025h/0xc00e0025

Tags: msmq, domaincontroller

I have installed MSMQ and MSMQ AD Integration on a domain controller which also hosts an Exchange server. The whole code has been used successfully on other domain controllers (none of which hosts an Exchange server; I sincerely hope that this is not the reason!).

As [required on a domain controller](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749102(v=ws.10).aspx#sectionSection2), I have used the following code to allow the network service account to create queues:

```csh
SecurityIdentifier sidNetworkService = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-20");
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule NewRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(sidNetworkService, ActiveDirectoryRights.CreateChild, AccessControlType.Allow, new Guid("9a0dc344-c100-11d1-bbc5-0080c76670c0"), ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance.All);
de.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(NewRule);
de.CommitChanges();
```

However, when trying to create/access a public queue, the following error occurs:

> A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951677/why-does-msmq-think-im-on-a-workgroup-computer), I have then uninstalled MSMQ and MSMQ AD Integration, installed it again, but the error is the same.

I verified that MSMQ is installed in Domain Mode by proving that `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters` has `Workgroup` set to `REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)`

So I have had a look into `eventvwr.msc` and found the following errors:

> The Message Queuing service failed to join the computer's domain 'EXCH'. Error 0xc00e0025:

and

> Message Queuing was unable to create the msmq (MSMQ Configuration) object in Active Directory Domain Services. Error c00e0025h:

These errors are already described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/622491/the-message-queuing-service-failed-to-join-the-computers-domain-domain-error), but without an accepted solution.

So, does someone have an idea where to find the culprit?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to use public queues?

Comment: @tomredfern I have a high-load application which may be installed on a cluster, and communication between the frontend servers and the backend service is through MSMQ.

Comment: If Workgroup = 0x00000001 then you are definitely NOT in AD integrated mode.

Comment: Public queues are only useful if you need to look them up in Active Directory first. If you already know the queue names then public queues are probably a waste of time.

Comment: As to the problem, you didn't have access permissions to create the necessary objects in AD. What account were you logged in with?

Comment: @JohnBreakwell I am a non-native, but I think that [this document](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749102(v=ws.10).aspx#sectionSection2) explicitly tells me to check that it is indeed 1.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell My IIS app pools are running as "NetworkService", the Windows service is running as "NetworkService" and the MSMQ service is also running as "NetworkService".

Comment: The account that installed MSMQ is relevant here, not the accounts used by it. If the account cannot create the initial AD objects, it will never work.

Comment: The document says that to start with it must be 1 but that's just to check you're not already AD-integrated. Workgroup=1 means workgroup mode,